# Carto Mobile SDK: How to zoom-in when cluster is clicked

Tags: carto-mobile

Carto Mobile SDK guide on clusters [states](https://carto.com/developers/mobile-sdk/guides/clustering/), that with cluster you can (among other options):

> Indicate the action when clicking on marker. For example, zoom in, or expand the cluster without zooming

I actually can't find any zoom in or expand cluster functionality/setting in Carto Mobile SDK. Has anyone successfully used it or do I have to implement the functionality myself?